# Get twitter followers using tweepy and multiple API keys

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have multiple twitter dev keys that I am using to get followers from a list of handles. There are two ways I can do this but have a problem with both. The first:

```
try:
    ....
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=screenName).items():
    ....
except tweepy.TweepError as e:

    errorCode = e.message[0]['code']
        if errorCode == 88:
            print "Rate limit exceeded."
            rotateKeys()
```

The issue here is that every time I rotate keys, the for loop starts from scratch and starts getting the followers again. I tried to get around this but splitting the for loop:

```
try:
    items = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=s).items()
```

I then loop through them manually using `next(items)`

However rotating api keys does not work as the initial call was done with the first API code and will always try to use that one.

I need a way to rotate keys and continue from were the previous left of.

Comment: Are you looking to do this real-time or would batch work? In case of batch, how about fetching different users under different application contexts/keys (using separate threads maybe?) and sleeping the required 15 minutes within the same app context while followers for a given user are being fetched?

Comment: No standard way AFAIK. You can implement caching for method's results or handle cursor initialization by hands by saving/manually restoring `self.current_page` variable.

Comment: Caching sounds interesting. How would I save the current page/item and then re-initialize from that cursor?

Comment: side comment: on the first place, shouldn't you rather rotate app user access Tokens rather than API keys? Be careful not to have your IP address blacklisted by twitter...

Answer (score 5):

I actually had to end up abandoning the cursored method in favor of manually setting the next cursor. The nice thing about this is that the "non-cursored" method returns the previous and next cursor as part of it's function.

Here's how I achieved what you are going for (note: adding a try/catch is probably in order):

```
users = ['user_one', 'user_two', 'user_three']

current_profile = 9 # I HAVE TEN IN AN ARRAY

tweepy_api = get_api(auth_profiles[current_profile]) #A FUNCTION I CREATED TO REINITIALIZE API'S

for user in users:

    next_cursor = -1 # START EVERY NEW USER RETRIEVAL WITH -1

    print 'CURRENT USER:', user, 'STARTING CURSOR:', next_cursor

    while next_cursor: # THAT IS, WHILE CURSOR IS NOT ZERO

        print 'AUTH PROFILE', current_profile, 'CURRENT CURSOR:', next_cursor

        # RETURNS A TUPLE WITH ELEMENT[0] A LIST OF IDS, ELEMENT [1][0] PREVIOUS CURSOR, AND ELEMENT[1][1] NEXT CURSOR
        ids, cursors = tweepy_api.followers_ids(screen_name=user, count=5000, cursor=next_cursor)

        next_cursor = cursors[1] # STORE NEXT CURSOR

        # FUNCTION I CREATED TO GET STATUS FROM API.rate_limit_status()
        status = get_rate_limit_status(tweepy_api, '/followers/ids')

        print 'ID\'S RETRIEVED:', len(ids), 'NEXT CURSOR:', cursors[1], 'REMAINING:', status['remaining']

        if not status['remaining']: # IF STATUS IS REMAINING IS ZERO

            print ''
            print 'RATE LIMIT REACHED'

            if current_profile < len(auth_profiles) - 1: # IF THE CURRENT PROFILE IS LESS THAN NINE (IN MY CASE)

                print 'INCREMENTING CURRENT PROFILE:', current_profile, '<', len(auth_profiles) - 1

                current_profile += 1 # INCREMENT THE PROFILE

                print 'CURRENT PROFILE:', current_profile

            else: # ELSE, IT MUST EQUAL NINE (COULD BE NEG I SUPPOSE BUT...)

                print 'RESETTING CURRENT PROFILE TO ZERO:', current_profile, '=', len(auth_profiles) - 1

                current_profile = 0 # RESET CURRENT PROFILE TO THE BEGINNING

                print 'CURRENT PROFILE:', current_profile

            tweepy_api = get_api(auth_profiles[current_profile]) # GET NEW TWEEPY API WITH NEW AUTH
            print ''
```

The output should be something like this (I've removed some of the print statements for simplicity):

```
CURRENT USER: user_one STARTING CURSOR: -1
AUTH PROFILE 9 CURRENT CURSOR: -1

ID'S RETRIEVED: 5000 NEXT CURSOR: 1594511885763407081 REMAINING: 14
…
ID'S RETRIEVED: 5000 NEXT CURSOR: 1582249691352919104 REMAINING: 0

RATE LIMIT REACHED
RESETTING CURRENT PROFILE TO ZERO: 9 = 9
CURRENT PROFILE: 0

ID'S RETRIEVED: 5000 NEXT CURSOR: 1580277475971792716 REMAINING: 14
…
ID'S RETRIEVED: 4903 NEXT CURSOR: 0 REMAINING: 7

CURRENT USER: user_two STARTING CURSOR: -1
AUTH PROFILE 0 CURRENT CURSOR: -1

ID'S RETRIEVED: 5000 NEXT CURSOR: 1592820762836029887 REMAINING: 6
…
ID'S RETRIEVED: 5000 NEXT CURSOR: 1592737463603654258 REMAINING: 0

RATE LIMIT REACHED
INCREMENTING CURRENT PROFILE: 0 < 9
CURRENT PROFILE: 1
```

As a side note, if you are going to use a cursored version, at least in Tweepy 3.5.0 the prev_cursor and next_cursor are stored in cursor.iterator.next_cursor, cursor.iterator.prev_cursor. I think this is also the case for 3.6.0 (see [Cursor](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/e8e779a017a4d42bcfc3de532df7d477fe4121ee/tweepy/cursor.py#L17) and [CursorIterator](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/e8e779a017a4d42bcfc3de532df7d477fe4121ee/tweepy/cursor.py#L66) in [cursor.py](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/cursor.py))

For me, cursor.page_iterator.next_cursor returns:

```
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'page_iterator'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the cursor that was used when the rate limit occured through the `next_cursor` variable on the iterator being used. When you create a new Cursor using the new API instance, you can pass the previous cursor as a parameter:

```
current_cursor = cursor.iterator.next_cursor
# re-create the cursor using the new api instance
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=s, cursor=current_cursor)
```

Comment: unfortunately I get this message: `AttributeError: 'ItemIterator' object has no attribute 'iterator'`

Comment: @saitam The correct name is **cursor.page_iterator.next_cursor** and works like Aaron said.