# tweepy error Failed to send request WSAECONNABORTED

Tags: python, tweepy

I am try to collect a complete list of followers of a user. The user has over 100,000 followers. Below is the code I am using. The code returns a few thousand followers, but then I get an error "tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: (10053, 'WSAECONNABORTED'). I am using a Windows machine.

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# get the followers' screen names 

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="xxxx", count = 200).items():
    print user.screen_name
```

Answer (score 0):

That process can take considerable time for that many followers. Something to the tune of 10 hours or longer. The odds of having some sort of error raised during that time is significant, and since you're not handling the errors in any way, you get to start over every time anything pops up.

Twitter uses cursors to allow for pagination. In other words it is possible to pick up where you left off, if you know what the current cursor is when your script fails.

Keep track of the cursor by using this:

```
    current_cursor = user.iterator.next_cursor
```

Print that, or write it to a file somewhere, so when the script fails, you can call:

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="xxxx", count = 200, cursor=current_cursor).items():
```

This should allow you to pick up where you left off. [Original solution posed for a different problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427674/get-twitter-followers-using-tweepy-and-multiple-api-keys)